# Using clValid in R getting Error in cutree.default(clusterObj, nc) : Function cutree is only available for hclust/dendrogram/phylo objects only

Tags: r, cluster-computing

Using the default data set from Brock et al., 2008

```
install.packages("clValid", dependencies = TRUE)
library(clValid)
data("mouse")
express <- mouse[, c("M1", "M2", "M3", "NC1", "NC2", "NC3")]
rownames(express) <- mouse$ID
intern <- clValid(express, 2:6, clMethods = c("hierarchical", "kmeans", "diana", "fanny", 
"som", "pam", "sota", "clara", "model"), validation = "internal")
```

and getting the following:

> Error in cutree.default(clusterObj, nc) :
>     Function cutree is only available for hclust/dendrogram/phylo objects only.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to come from the fact that `stats::cutree` is masked by `dendextend::cutree` once the package `dendextend`is loaded and that `dendextend::cutree` does not work for objects generated with some functions of the `cluster` package like `diana` and `agnes` (while `stats::cutree` works fine).

**EDIT** : this problem was observed with `dendextend` 1.9.0 but has been very quickly fixed by the package author after [bug report](https://github.com/talgalili/dendextend/issues/90). The new version 1.10.0 works perfectly fine with `cluster` and the `clValid` version from the CRAN. 
It can be installed via : 
`devtools::install_github("talgalili/dendextend")`

This is the best solution now. I let here the rest of my initial answer below for the archives only.

---

Some code to test that (everything works fine without `dendextend` but loading `dendextend` triggers the error message :

```
# detach(package:dendextend)
# library(dendextend)
# 
library(cluster)
d <- iris[,-5]
cl <- diana(dist(d))
cutree(cl, 3)
cl <- agnes(dist(d))
cutree(cl, 3)

library(clValid)
intern <- clValid(d, 2:10,
                  clMethods = c("hierarchical", "kmeans", "diana", "fanny",
                                "model", "pam", "agnes"),
                  method = "ward", validation = "internal")
```

Sadly `clValid` seems to be orphaned so it is not possible to ask the developer to change the code (or am I wrong ?).

Solutions :

- do not use `dendextend` and `clValid` at the same time
- do not use `agnes` and `diana` in the `clMethods` argument of `clValid`
- I have forked the `clValid` github repository (from CRAN) and made the small changes necessary in the code. You can install this version with `devtools::install_github("GillesSanMartin/clValid")`. It works for me also when `dendextend` is loaded.

Comment: The most recent version of dendextend now has this problem fixed (version 1.10.0, see: https://github.com/talgalili/dendextend/issues/90. Thanks for the bug report)